# Как преобразовать ссылку mod rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый день, помогите с mod rewrite. Хочу преобразовать ссылку.
С одной переменной понятно

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.+)?$ index.php?news=$1 [L,QSA]
```

В результате получаю `site.ru/news/{news_id}`

А что делать если несколько переменных?

Ссылка: `index.php?news=123&city=moscow`

Как перенаправить чтобы получить ссылку вида `site.ru/news/{city_id}/{news_id}`?

Answer (score 0):

Лучше взять готовый роутер на php, например [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) и задать нужные правила.

А для .htaccess можно сделать так:

```
# в город может попасть любой символ, в новость только цифры
RewriteRule ^news/([^\/]+)/(\d+)$ index.php?news=$2&city=$1 [L,QSA]
# если не сработало правило для конкретного города, проверяем только номер новости
RewriteRule ^news/(\d+)$ index.php?news=$1 [L,QSA]
```

P.S. Путь вида `site.ru/news/` обработан этими правилами не будет.